# How does AWS Athena scale with data scanned size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have table with S3 JSON as a source partitioned by:

```
year
month
day
hour
```

With `projection.enabled = true` and standard ranges for these partition keys.
Running query like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table WHERE year=2022 and month=10 and day=28 or day=29 or day=30
```

Took:

- 8 seconds for one day,
- 25 seconds for two days,
- 48 seconds for three days

How can I predict how will this scale?Initially I expected the time to be constant - I thought Athena would spin up as many "crawlers" as many files there are to be scanned.

Can I predict how will this scale?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way you can predict this on Athena. You're running your queries on a shared cluster with huge, but ultimately limited resources. At busy times your query might even be queued for quite a bit before anything gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is very hard to predict how Athena scales, I can say that V3 engine works much faster than V2 engine.